# Instance created via Service Account unable to use Google Cloud Speech API - authentication error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I followed Google's Quick-Start documentation for the Speech API to enable billing and API for an account. This account has authorized a service account to create Compute instances on its behalf. After creating an instance on the child account, hosting a binary to use the Speech API, I am unable to successfully use the example C# code provided by Google in the C# speech example:

```
try
        {
            var speech = SpeechClient.Create();                
            var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                LanguageCode = "en"
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile(audioFiles[0]));
            foreach (var result in response.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                }
            }
      } catch (Exception ex)
      // ...
      }
```

Requests fail on the `SpeechClient.Create()` line with the following error:

> ---
>
> --------------------------- Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unauthenticated, Detail="Exception occured in
>   metadata credentials plugin.")
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at Grpc.Core.Internal.AsyncCall`2.UnaryCall(TRequest msg)
>
> at
>   Grpc.Core.Calls.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](CallInvocationDetails`2
>   call, TRequest req)
>
> at
>   Grpc.Core.DefaultCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2
>   method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
>
> at
>   Grpc.Core.Internal.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2
>   method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
>
> at
>   Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.Speech.SpeechClient.Recognize(RecognizeRequest
>   request, CallOptions options)
>
> at
>   Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.b__1(TRequest
>   req, CallSettings cs)
>
> at
>   Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.b__0(TRequest
>   request, CallSettings callSettings)
>
> at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.Sync(TRequest request,
>   CallSettings perCallCallSettings)
>
> at
>   Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.SpeechClientImpl.Recognize(RecognizeRequest
>   request, CallSettings callSettings)
>
> at Google.Cloud.Speech.V1.SpeechClient.Recognize(RecognitionConfig
>   config, RecognitionAudio audio, CallSettings callSettings)
>
> at Rc2Solver.frmMain.RecognizeWordsGoogleSpeechApi() in
>   C:\Users\jorda\Google
>   Drive\VSProjects\Rc2Solver\Rc2Solver\frmMain.cs:line 1770
>
> ### --------------------------- OK

I have verified that the Speech API is activated. Here is the scope that the service account uses when creating the Compute instances:

```
credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
                new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(me)
                {
                    Scopes = new[] { ComputeService.Scope.Compute, ComputeService.Scope.CloudPlatform }
                }.FromPrivateKey(yk)

                );
```

I have found no information or code online about specifically authorizing or authenticating the Speech API for service account actors. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was that the Cloud Compute instances needed to be created with a ServiceAccount parameter specified. Otherwise the Cloud instances were not part of a ServiceAccount default credential, which is referenced by the `SpeechClient.Create()` call. Here is the proper way to create an instance attached to a service account, and it will use the SA tied to the project ID:

```
service = new ComputeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer() {
 HttpClientInitializer = credential,
  ApplicationName = "YourAppName"
});

string MyProjectId = "example-project-27172";
var project = await service.Projects.Get(MyProjectId).ExecuteAsync();
ServiceAccount servAcct = new ServiceAccount() {
 Email = project.DefaultServiceAccount,
  Scopes = new [] {
   "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
  }
};


Instance instance = new Instance() {
 MachineType = service.BaseUri + MyProjectId + "/zones/" + targetZone + "/machineTypes/" + "g1-small",
  Name = name,
  Description = name,
  Disks = attachedDisks,
  NetworkInterfaces = networkInterfaces,
  ServiceAccounts = new [] {
   servAcct
  },
  Metadata = md
};

batchRequest.Queue < Instance > (service.Instances.Insert(instance, MyProjectId, targetZone),
 (content, error, i, message) => {
  if (error != null) {
   AddEventMsg("Error creating instance " + name + ": " + error.ToString());
  } else {
   AddEventMsg("Instance " + name + " created");
  }
 });
```